# Infinite template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

Here's my simplified test code:

```
struct Test {
    Test() { run(0); }

    template<class T>
    static auto run(T&&, bool stop = false) -> void { if (!stop) _run<T>(); }
    template<class R>
    static auto _run() -> void { [] () { run([] () {}, true); }(); }
};
```

When I compiled this code with GCC and clang, it gives compilation error:

```
/media/data/caca3d/src/b0util/test/tst_promise.cpp:30: error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)
 static auto _run() -> void { [] () { run([] () {}, true); }(); }
                                      ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can't see why this code causes infinite template instantiation.

FYI, If I remove `template<class R>` in `_run()` function, the errors gone.

I found this error when trying some lazy evaluation with lambda function, so I cannot remove indirect call in lambda.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do you really need _run to be a template in the first place?

Comment: Yes. This code is just simplified one for test. Actual code utilizes template and template metaprogramming heavily.

Comment: ok, thanks for creating the MCVE then =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at what is happening. The first function explicitly calls a templated version of `_run()`, I suppose you have no questions over this part.

```
template<class T>
static auto run(T&&, bool stop = false) -> void { if (!stop) _run<T>(); }
```

The second one is more interesting. It may seem that it will only be instantiated once (since you are just calling `run()` once with a lambda), but each lambda, according to the standard, has it's own unique type, so each time `_run()` is instantiated it will force the creation of a new version of `run()` (since `T` is deduced from the function's argument type), creating an infinite loop.

```
template<class R>
static auto _run() -> void { [] () { run([] () {}, true); }(); }
```

The easiest way to solve this problem in this particular example would be to make `run()` take an `std::function` of a particular (maybe template parameter-dependant) type that matches your lambda.

Comment: Thank you for quick and clear answer. Maybe I'll try to use std::function which has finite instantiated types instead of lambda. Thanks alot.

Comment: @xylosper, yep, that's exactly what I was going to suggest =)

Comment: @xylosper, by the way (not sure if you'll actually need it, but it's a nice feature), you can make `std::function`s based on parameter packs, for example `template<class ReturnType, class ... ArgumentTypes> class function_wrapper { public: std::function<ReturnType(ArgumentTypes...)> functionPointer};`

Comment: Thank you for advice. I've used variadic templatized std::function before.